# hibernate nativesql select not working. it is returning empty objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I wrote a small program to get the list of things from Database by using Hibernate native sql. I am getting blank objects from Data Base.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

                //2 Loading hibernate configuration file
                conf.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

                SessionFactory factory = conf.buildSessionFactory();

                Session session = factory.openSession();

                SQLQuery qq = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT Employee_Name, EMployee_id, Address FROM employee");
                List<Object[]> l = qq.list();
                System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::"+l.size());
                Iterator itr = l.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                    Object[] objs = (Object[])itr.next();
                    System.out.println(objs[0].toString());
                }
```

the size of the list is same as the size of the databse. But the obj is coming as blank and when i tried printing values it is giving outofbound exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvKGP.png)

Answer (score 0):

When i look at the API , https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list() , the following is the way it works

```
enter code here@Test
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void testEmployee() {
    SQLQuery employeeList = hibernateSession
            .createSQLQuery("SELECT employeeName, employeeId, Address FROM Employee");
    List<Object[]> resultObjects = employeeList.list();
    Assert.assertNotNull(resultObjects);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, resultObjects.size());
    // System.out.println(employees.get(0).getClass().getName());
    for (Object[] employeeObject : resultObjects) {
        Assert.assertEquals("Ram", employeeObject[0]);
        Assert.assertEquals("R18676", employeeObject[1]);
        Assert.assertEquals("Bangalore, India", employeeObject[2]);
    }
}
```

12:44:08.719 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - SELECT employeeName, employeeId, A
ddress FROM Employee
Hibernate: SELECT employeeName, employeeId, Address FROM Employee
12:44:08.724 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
12:44:08.724 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row:
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.714 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: in my case the result objects are coming as null (as shown in the screen shot attached). I tried in the above way as well. it did not work

Comment: Can you share your bean and hibernate cfg as well please

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved after updating the hibernate version to 3.2. Previously i was using 3.0.1